# PostgreSQL 9.6 won't connect on Ubuntu 16

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.6

I installed PostgreSQL 9.6 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.  It seems like it's up and running, but when I try to make a connection it just fails.  When I run the status command I see that it's always saying `exited` for some reason.  I see lots of things in a google search but none seem to be helping.

I changed the first entry in the pg_hba.conf to be `local all postgres trust`

> % ps augxw | grep postg
>   postgres   769  0.0  0.3 303964 24384 ?        S    22:13   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -c   config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
>   postgres   772  0.0  0.0 303964  3956 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: checkpointer process
>   postgres   773  0.0  0.0 303964  3956 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: writer process
>   postgres   774  0.0  0.0 303964  3956 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: wal writer process
>   postgres   775  0.0  0.0 304408  6572 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: autovacuum launcher process
>   postgres   776  0.0  0.0 158964  3204 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: stats collector process
>   ubuntu    1492  0.0  0.0  12944   936 pts/0    S+   22:14   0:00 grep postg
>   %
>   % sudo su - postgres
>   $ psql -h localhost
>   psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   $ exit
>   logout
>   % systemctl status postgresql
>   ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-03-30 22:13:57 PDT; 1min 19s ago
>     Process: 901 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>    Main PID: 901 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>       Tasks: 0
>      Memory: 0B
>         CPU: 0
>      CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
>
> Mar 30 22:13:57 ip-172-31-9-223 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
>   Mar 30 22:13:57 ip-172-31-9-223 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

Comment: Is that Desktop or Server? How did you get 9.6? Clean install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.2 LTS gets only 9.5. Did you add official Postgres repo?

Comment: I installed the "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" repository via the instructions at http://askubuntu.com/questions/831292/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-any-ubuntu-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that version 9.5 had the normal 5432 port and so when 9.6 got installed/started, it pointed to 5433.  Deleting the 9.5 install and editing the config file to point at 5432 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting using `TCP/IP` socket, but `local` refers to unix-domain socket.

> The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a plain TCP/IP socket.

I did install postgresql-9.6 from that repo and:

1. `host   all             postgres         127.0.0.1/32            trust` does what you want to do
2. `postgres@lkaminski-ubuntu-desk:~$ psql` works out of the box, no need to change config. It is using unix-domain socket that is already trusted. So you can just drop `-h localhost` and no need to edit configs.

`$ sudo grep -e "^[^#]" /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
host   all             postgres         127.0.0.1/32            trust
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Still not working for me.  Can you show all the (non-commented) conf lines in your pg_hba file?  Mine's been mucked wtih multiple times now.

Comment: I made mine look like yours.  Still no luck.  I believe the real issue here is that the status says exited when I run the systemctl command.

Comment: No, that isn't it. Mine gives the same-ish output for `systemctl status postgresql`. Did you try to connect without using hostname?